# Probability "average" understanding

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, problem-solving

This is more of a problem understanding probabilities than an actual question.

In a game I am playing I can use a certain item to try to unlock different levels.

The item will unlock a new level based on those probabilities:

```
Level 1: 32.68%
Level 2: 29.41%
Level 3: 26.14%
Level 4: 9.80%
Level 5: 1.63%
Level 6: 0.33%
```

A user has suggested that those probabilities can be interpreted as following:

```
300 items on average to get a level 6.
16.4% chance of getting a level 6 using 50 items.
28.4% chance of getting a level 6 using 100 items.
63.4% chance of getting a level 6 using 300 items.
96.5% chance of getting a level 6 using 1000 items.
```

Now I understand how to calculate the probabilities to get to level 6 with *X* amount of tries.

1. Calculate the chance to NOT get to level 6 with a single item, in
   this case it's 0.967.
2. Multiply this number with itself *X* times.
3. Deduct the number produced from the previous calculation from 1.

What I fail to understand is how he calculates the "average" items needed to get to the 6th level and I hope you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of the chance not to get a level 6 item is off-you slipped a decimal.  On one try it is $0.9967$  You have a [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) of the time to success.  For a geometric distribution the average time to success is the inverse of the chance of success on the first try.  As $\frac 1{0.0033} \approx 300$ ( it is really $303.\overline {03}$) the expected number of tries is about $300$